# Somethings wrong with my colliders (Unity Game Engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a character, that has a character controller attached to it I am using `transform.position`, `transform.forward` and `transform.rotate` to move with the `'wasd'` keys, that all works fine.

However it will not collide with any sort of colliders, whether is be box colliders or mesh colliders. trigger works on my character, i.e. it can trigger an object to destroy if it passes through, but the colliders that are not set to triggers (like walls), don't block the player, the player just goes through them.

Any ideas?

*Note*: using `C#`, `unity` free *version 4.5.1*

Comment: `rigidBody` and `collider` component is required on your character

Comment: I see you are using a box collider so i assume you are working in 2D so `rigidBody2D` is what you require.

Comment: nope, deosnt fix it, just tried it, player still goes through walls, cant add 2D rigidbody, it conflicts with the character controller.

Comment: Are you using `CharacterController2D`? If not the wrong type of `rigidBody ` maybe attached.

Comment: No, im using regular character controller, ive tried to attach both types of rigidbody, does not work, player still goes through colliders.

Comment: Is your character moving very fast? `transform translate` performs tiny teleportations and can pass the edges of colliders at fast speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i figured out the problem, as the previous answer said i should not use transform with character controller, however there's no need to change any colliders, i still kept my character controller on my player, but rather i used controller.SimpleMove to move the character, that fixes the problem and i get to keep the character controller on my object (no need to add extra colliders or rigidbody to the player).

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html

Answer (score 1):

You Should not use transform for colliding.

Add ridged body and get reference to ridgedbody.
Then use reference.addForce